# JTextField setText() expensive

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

The application I am writing requires lots of JTextFields to be updated many times a second so that they contain the current information about an object which the user can change (X, Y position etc.). The problem I am finding is that the setText() method appears to be too expensive to use this much for the application to run smoothly. I have tested the program without string formatting and without the switch statement which saved me about 10fps making the application run at 40fps instead of 30 when ideally I need a solid 60. This is when have 10 particle data panels on the screen (1 data panel contains 7 ParticleFields). This is my first program using the Swing library so I'm sure either my code is horribly inefficient, or there is an alternative way of tackling the task at hand.

```
public class ParticleField extends JTextField{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2181907591904112074L;
    public static int M = 0;
    public static int X = 1;
    public static int Y = 2;
    public static int XV = 3;
    public static int YV = 4;
    public static int XP = 5;
    public static int YP = 6;

    public static final Font FONT = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24);

    public Particle p;
    public int type;

    public boolean isSelected = false;
    public boolean wasSelected = false;


    public ParticleField(Particle p, int t){
        this.p = p;
        this.type = t;

        setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        setFont(FONT);

        getDocument().addDocumentListener(new txtDocumentListener(this));
        addFocusListener(new txtBoxListener());

        getParticleData();

    }
    public Particle getP(){
        return p;
    }
    public void setParticleData(){
        switch (type) {
            case 0: p.setM(Double.parseDouble(getText())); break;
            case 1: p.setXM(Double.parseDouble(getText())); break;
            case 2: p.setYM(Double.parseDouble(getText())); break;
            case 3: p.setXVM(Double.parseDouble(getText())); break;
            case 4: p.setYVM(Double.parseDouble(getText())); break;
            case 5: getParticleData(); break;
            case 6: getParticleData(); break;   
        }
    }
    public void getParticleData(){
        setText("swag");
        switch (type) {
            case 0: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getM())); break;
            case 1: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getXM())); break;
            case 2: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getYM())); break;
            case 3: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getXVM())); break;
            case 4: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getYVM())); break;
            case 5: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getXPM())); break;
            case 6: setText(String.format("%.2f",p.getYPM())); break;
        }
    }

    public class txtBoxListener implements FocusListener {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            ParticleField t = (ParticleField) e.getSource();
            t.isSelected = true;

        }
        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            ParticleField t = (ParticleField) e.getSource();
            t.isSelected = false;
            t.setParticleData();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're updating it quickly, can we assume that it's read-only (from the user's point of view)? If so, then JTextField is the wrong element type. Try a JLabel.

Comment: Ideally the user should be able to edit the data while the simulation is running, however if it comes down to it I may make it so the user has to pause the simulation to change the values, and then use JLables to display the values as they change while the simulation runs. This is assuming the JLabels setTxt() equivalent method is less expensive?

Comment: JTable may be even better for this situation

Comment: If you're updating the field 60 times a second, the user is unlikely to have enough time to enter a value and hit the submit button. You will need two fields: an input and an output.

Comment: https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/collision-lab this is an example of what I am trying to achieve. Under the Advanced tab and click on more data. It allows the user to edit the text while the simulation runs, however it sounds as if this is not achievable using a JTextField.

Comment: `JLabel` is lighter weight than `JTextField`. I haven't run metrics on it, but I think it's a good guess to say `JLabel#setText()` is at least slightly faster than `JTextField#setText()`.

Comment: I would use a JLabel and a JTextField. You can put a listener on the JLabel so that it "turns into" the JTextField when it receives focus (hiding / showing the correct fields on the correct events). The user won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Excellent idea, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Nothing says you have to update the everything at the same rate.